# Replacing empty messages in all history

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository imported from Subversion, and many of commits have empty messages. Is there any way to run over all history and replace every empty message interactively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git rebase --interactive <first commit>`; I've used it many time for just this purpose.

This will present you with a list of commits, oldest on top with `pick` next to them.  Below this, in a commented section are instructions on the various options that allow you to change the commit, reword the commit message,  squash commits together into one or even remove commits completely.

A few references for further reading:

- [git rebase manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)
- [**Git Pro** book section on Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)
- [**Git Pro** book section on rewriting history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) (includes a section to change multiple commit messages)

Be aware that, as the last reference suggests, this rewrites history.  This can cause problems for anyone that has cloned the repository already.